# Angular2+ template syntax for local variable inside *ngFor

Tags: angular, local-variables, ngfor, angular-template

I have a utility method that gets called twice within each iteration of an *ngFor loop of an Ionic 3 app (which uses Angular4 under covers). (something akin to getIndex2 below).

Is there a way to assign a local variable and reference that, so utility method isn't called twice per iteration?

Something of the form:

```
<div *ngfor="let item of items;
             let i = index; 
             let j = getIndex2(items[i]); 
             let k = items[j]">
  {{k.property1}}
  {{k.property2}}
</div>
```

It may use `as`, or `#` syntax too, but it would be nice to know if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure what `getIndex2()` does, but if you just want to reference the current item all you need to do is:

```
<div *ngfor="let item of items">
   {{ item.property1 }}
   {{ item.property2 }}
</div>
```

But I assume that is not the case. What you otherwise need to do is handle that piece of logic outside of your template markup. For example:

```
this.items = this.items.map((item) => item.otherItem = this.getIndex2(item));
```

And then:

```
<div *ngfor="let item of items">
   {{ item.otherItem.property1 }}
   {{ item.otherItem.property2 }}
</div>
```

Comment: That doesn't tell me something I wasn't already aware of. It's the call to the utility method that I need not to be recomputed.

Comment: You need to refactor your code, it is not valid. The `*ngFor`-directive takes four variables: index, first, last, even. That's it. What you need to do is put your logic in your component class (or service).

Comment: There must be some way to store a result of a method call inside the loop then, so it's only called once, when you need it twice or more times... So computation only occurs once.. Some sort of lazy loading caching in utllity method would be other alternative - but getting into making stateful code is something I'd rather avoid.